# Добавить и убрать класс блоку при клике на ссылку с одним и тем же классом

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть код

```
$(function() {
    $('html').click(function() {
        removeActiveMenuClass();
    });
    $( '.ibtn' ).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(), e.stopPropagation();
        removeActiveMenuClass();
        $(this).children('.dropdown').addClass('open');
    });
    function removeActiveMenuClass(){
        $('.ibtn').children('.dropdown').removeClass('open');
    }
});
```

Он рабочий, только мне ещё нужно, чтобы при повторном клике на кнопку блок убирался что то-типа `toggleClass`, сейчас же класс `.open` не убирается при повторном клике, хотелось сделать подобное как на сайте https://trend-spb.ru/metro/rybackoe блок фильтров.

Comment: Как-то непонятно вопрос поставлен

Comment: Ну может сделаешь .toggleClass('open') вместо addClass ?

Comment: Пробовал, не работает.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, код по ссылке сработал отлично.

Answer (score 0):

Вся проблема в функции `removeActiveMenuClass()` или в том, как вы её используете. В этой части кода:

```
$( '.ibtn' ).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(), e.stopPropagation();
    removeActiveMenuClass();
    $(this).children('.dropdown').addClass('open');
});
```

При клике на элемент `.ibtn` сначала удаляется стандартное поведение и дальнейшая передача события (второе скорее всего лишнее, но не в этом суть). Далее вызывается функция `removeActiveMenuClass()`, которая удаляет класс `open` у **всех(включая текущий)** `.dropdown` , а после снова добавляет класс `open`. Поэтому, чтобы работал метод `toggleClass()` нужно удалять класс `open` у всех, кроме текущего.

Как вариант можно использовать метод `.not`:

```js
$(function() {
    $(document).click(function() {
        removeActiveMenuClass();
    });
    $( '.ibtn' ).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(), e.stopPropagation();
        $('.ibtn').not(this).children('.dropdown').removeClass('open');
        $(this).children('.dropdown').toggleClass('open');
    });
    function removeActiveMenuClass(){
        $('.ibtn').children('.dropdown').removeClass('open');
    }
});
```

```css
.dropdown {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown.open {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="ibtn">
  Click
  <div class="dropdown">I'm dropdown</div>
</a>
```

Comment: Спасибо что откликнулись, но я воспользовался кодом по ссылке выше, в вашем примере при клике по открывшемуся блоку происходит его закрытие, т.е. класс open убирается и даже не выбрать что нужно в нем. Но все равно спасибо!